Can you cast a copy of a card from the battlefield if the effect creating the copy specifies that it can be cast?
I recently saw a post on r/BadMtgCombos about an interesting combo, the combo works as following (text copied from the author, credit to u/Gamesfreak13563):

First, get Transmogrifying Licid and Spellweaver Volute on the
field, and make Volute an artifact with Liquimetal Coating.
Panharmonicon doubles Idris, Soul of the TARDIS' enters the
battlefield trigger, and thanks to rule 607.3 Idris can exile both the
Licid and the Volute and gets the activated and triggered abilities of
both. It doesn't, however, get any of their static abilities,
including Spellweaver Volute's enchant ability.
Once that's done, activate Idris' Licid ability to turn it into an
aura that enchants a creature. It doesn't have Volute's enchant
ability, just the enchant ability from the Licid, so it can legally
enchant a creature. Because of Rule 303.4m, the triggered ability on
Idris from Spellweaver Volute refers to the attached permanent, so
when you cast a sorcery, you create a copy of the card that Idris is
attached to.
Now, you'd think that you'd cast the copy, exiling your enchanted
creature causing your Idris to sacrifice itself when it can't attach
to anything else, but actually don't: Rule 707.12 says that the copy
of an object is created in the same zone that the object is in, which
in this case, is the battlefield. And Rule 704.5e says that a copy of
a card can exist on the battlefield. So, you create a copy of the card
on the battlefield, don't cast it, and then it just stays there. And
since you didn't cast the copy of the card, you don't have to exile
the card and you don't have to sacrifice Idris.

My question is, could you choose to cast the copy from the battlefield, or is there any rule preventing you from casting things from the battlefield? And if you can, would you need to sacrifice Idris due to it not being able to enchant an instant in a graveyard, or could you save idris by ending the licid effect since it's a special action?

I feel like the bit about using the special action to save Idris should be its own question, as it's basically unrelated to the main question.

Yes, you may cast a spell from the battlefield.
The rules for casting spells are fully general as far as the origin zone is concerned:

601.2. To cast a spell is to take it from where it is (usually the hand), put it on the stack, and pay its costs, so that it will eventually resolve and have its effect. [..]


Excellent, thanks! A further question if you or anyone else happens to know, let's say I mutated the enchanted creature, when I copy the merged creature and choose to cast it for free, what happens? Will I cast one spell with the characteristics of the merged creature, cast two spells being the two creatures separated, or something else?

@Allure: The combo as described uses the "may" in "You may cast the copy without paying its mana cost" on Spellweaver Volute (emphasis mine).  You copy the enchanted creature, choose not to copy it, and boom, you have your copy sitting pretty on the battlefield.

Yes, you can cast the card. This is because an effect says you can do so, which applies regardless of the zone the card is in. A trivial example is Squee, the Immortal, which simply states that you can cast it from specific zones other than your hand (namely, from your graveyard or from exile).
Note that if the effect says "you may cast the card" without further qualifications:

you must pay the mana cost and any required additional costs, or an alternative cost if one exists;
you may pay any optional additional costs;
you must specify valid target(s) if the spell requires them (e.g. an Aura with enchant creature cannot be cast if there are no creatures on the battlefield); and
you cannot get a land onto the battlefield this way (as a land cannot be cast as a spell).

If the effect states "you may cast the card without paying its mana cost":

you cannot choose to pay its mana cost or any alternate costs

which means that if {X} is in the mana cost, X can only be 0;


you must pay any required additional costs; and
you may pay any optional additional costs.


The question in your title and the one in your body are actually different

Can you cast a copy of a card from the battlefield if the effect creating the copy specifies that it can be cast?

Yes.

My question is, could you choose to cast the copy from the battlefield

No. Unless you have a way of getting an object on the battlefield that is both an instant and a creature, the combo doesn't work, so you can't get the copy, let alone cast it; the ability "Copy Enchanted Instant" allows you to copy only an Instant.

Because of Rule 303.4m, the triggered ability on Idris from Spellweaver Volute refers to the attached permanent, so when you cast a sorcery, you create a copy of the card that Idris is attached to.

Rule 303.4m is just clarifying Idris' ability would apply even if Idris were not an Enchantment. It is not saying that Idris' ability applies to objects that aren't of the specified property.

This is incorrect. Idris will not have "Enchant instant in a graveyard" because Idris only copies the Activated and Triggered abilities of the card(s) she exiled, and "Enchant X" is a Static ability (702.5a). Since the activated ability of the Licid is the only thing that makes her an aura and it gives her just "Enchant Creature", that is the only enchant ability she will have,

@Andrew Good point. I think the other point stands, though.

Perhaps, it's an odd situation, but a plain reading of 303.4m would have me ruling that it did work as the reddit post says, it shouldn't, it's an unintended edge case for sure, but all the actual RAW support it.

The combo works fine. The phrasing "the enchanted instant" is only for readability. Under the hood, it always means "the enchanted object" and so applies to any type of object.
